# Haskell вывод в консоль построчно

Tags: io, haskell

Есть функция и мне надо вывести построчно

```
x y результат
```

все никаких больше символов, как это сделать чтобы эта ... нормально вывела на каждую строку без лишних символов в консоль.

Единственный вариант но только с одним аргументом который я нашел

```
main = print([f1 x1 0 | x1 <- [0.0,0.1..10.0]])
```

Comment: Разбиваете знаками "\n" список "x, y, результат" и получается одна большая строка, ее и печатаете. Сам результат f - он печататься может, есть ли для этого типа show? Что выводит f, Double?

Comment: Если бы я знал как печатать строку. Тип show я не использовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо сформировать список строк, которые вы хотите напечатать и дальше действовать как [описано здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297298/1758363): 
либо мапить print на список, либо unline использовать.

Что-то например такое:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
import Data.List
-- функция двух аргументов, пример
f a b = a + b 

as = [1, 2, 3]
bs = [4, 5, 6]
-- res = zipWith f as bs

showAll f as bs = [showLine a b (f a b) | a <- as | b <-bs] 
    where showLine a b res = intercalate " " $ map show [a, b, res]

main = mapM_ print $ showAll f as bs

-- *Main> main
-- "1 4 5"
-- "2 5 7"
-- "3 6 9"
```

Comment: Это работает только если списки одинаковой длины? Если списки будут неодинаковыми как работать с ними?

Comment: C разной длиной обурбит до самого короткого списка из `as` и `bs`, можете попробовать с `as = [1, 2, 3, 200, 200]`

Comment: Отлинковал [сюда](https://github.com/epogrebnyak/haskell-intro/blob/master/stackoverflow/lineprint.hs)

Answer (score 0):

Функция `putStr` (без суффикса `Ln`) не выводит символ `\n` в конце. Примените её.

Comment: Уже пробовал, * Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `Double'
    * In the expression: f1 x1 2. Тут и есть в этом проблема.

Comment: Ну надо же еще в строку перевести: `putStr (show x)`

Comment: Как в вашем варианте можно реализовать мой 'x y результат'?

Comment: `putStr (show x)`, `putStr " "`, `putStr (show y)` и т.д. Или сразу `putStrLn $ show x ++ " " ++ show y ++ " " ++ show (f x y)`